# react hook, how to highlight current row on click and un-highlight other rows at the same time

Tags: reactjs

```js
const SheetTable = ({ sheets }) => {
    return (
        <table className="sheetTableComponent">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>No</td>
                    <td>track</td>
                    <td>item</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {sheets.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{index}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>{item.code}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>{item.item}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

This is my table. After populate it got about 10 rows. I want if one row click, it will highlight, the other rows un-highlight

Comment: are you looking for `tr:active {}` css?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqq4ty?file=src%2FSheet.js

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will solve your problem.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
 changeColor = (id) => {
    this.setState({ selected: id });
  };
  render() {
    const { selected, arr } = this.state;
    return (
      <table className="sheetTableComponent">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>track</td>
            <td>item</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {arr.map((item, index) => (
            <tr
              key={index}
              style={{
                color: selected === item.id ? "red" : ""
              }}
              onClick={() => this.changeColor(item.id)}
            >
              <td>{index}</td>
              <td>
                <div>{item.code}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div>{item.item}</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-color-of-clicked-list-item-so-forked-ostzg?file=/src/index.js:585-1301)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do it, but most simple is to just use css

Assign `tabindex` to your rows and use `:focus` selector to highlight the row

```
<tr key={index} className="row" tabindex="0">
```

**CSS:**

```
.row:focus { 
  outline: none;
  background: green;
}
```